# Dynamic Rows Going Vertically Down and Create Column after Six Rows

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a dynamic rows like this:

[1]  [7]  [13]

[2]  [8] [14]

[3]  [9]  [15]

[4]  [10]

[5]  [11]

[6] [12]

Currently, I have it output like this:

[1] [2] [3]

[4]  [5]  [6]

[7]  [8]  [9]

[10]  [11]  [12]

[13]  [14]  [15]

I want to output alphabetically/numerically down 6 rows before creating another column. The code below is for creating 3 data in one row then create another row for another 3 data and so on. My apologies for not being able to attach an image of what I like to output.

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT name FROM categories WHERE parent_id=1 ORDER BY order_id ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Query failed");

$numrows = (mysql_num_rows ($result));


if($numrows >0){
echo "<table width = 100% border = '0' cellspacing = '2' cellpadding = '0'><tr>";

for ( $i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) 
{

    echo "<td width='33%'>";

    while ($friendList = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

     $end = '<div class="left">'.$friendList['name'].'</div>'; 
      if ( isset($friendList[$j+6] )) 
      { 
        $end = '<div class="right">'.$friendList[$j+6].'</div>'; 
      } 
     echo $end."\n"; 

    }
    echo "</td>";
}
echo $end."</tr></table> ";

}

?>
```

Thank You.

Comment: hay did you get an answer for this any where? im trying to achieve this also with no success - thanks

Answer (score -2):

Since you know the number of rows returned, `$numrows`, then you can utilize that to pre-build your table and assemble after you are finished looping through your records.

```
$maxRows = 6;
$numCols = ceil($numRows / $maxRows);
```

During the construction of your table you will loop through the values returned and assign the output to an array.  Once all of your records have been added, you will then assemble and output the table.

*Note: You will want to make sure that your records are ordered appropriately in your query as the numbering is solely for indexing.*

```
<?php

$numRows = 41;
$maxRows = 6;
$numCols = ceil($numRows / $maxRows);

$records = array();

for($i=1; $i <= $maxRows; $i++){
    $records[$i] = array();
}

for($i=1; $i <= $numRows; $i++){
    $row = ($i % $maxRows == 0 ? $maxRows : $i % $maxRows);
    $records[$row][]  = "[$i]";
}

$table = ['<table>'];

for($i=1; $i <= count($records); $i++){
    $row = ['<tr>'];
    $col = $records[$i];

    for($j=0; $j < count($col); $j++){

        /*
         * Begin modification area:
         * 
         * You would change the value of $col[$j] to reflect the desired 
         * output within each cell.
         */

         $output = $col[$j];

        /* End modification area */

         $row[$j+1] = '<td>' . $output . '</td>';
    }
    array_push($row, '</tr>');
    $table[$i] = implode('', $row);
}

$table[$i++] = '</table>';
echo implode('', $table);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
[1] [7]  [13] [19] [25] [31] [37] 
[2] [8]  [14] [20] [26] [32] [38] 
[3] [9]  [15] [21] [27] [33] [39] 
[4] [10] [16] [22] [28] [34] [40] 
[5] [11] [17] [23] [29] [35] [41] 
[6] [12] [18] [24] [30] [36]
```